# How to fix table already created and values not showing up in console with SQL in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm in a Java class and the assignment is to create a table that will show the first ten values of pre-selected columns. However, when I run my code, with the sql running the way it is it says that my table is already created. I was wondering if there was a way for it to stop erroring out when that happens and to still show my code? Also when I set up a new table, the values that I need, (Income, ID, Pep) won't show up, just the headers I established before the syntax will. How would I make these fixes so it stops erroring out and I see my values in the console log?

This is running in eclipse, extended with prior project files from the class i'm taking. I've tried adding prepared statements, attempted to parse for strings to other variables and attempted syntax to achieve the values I need.

LoanProccessing.java file (Main file):

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class LoanProcessing extends BankRecords {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BankRecords br = new BankRecords();
        br.readData();
        Dao dao = new Dao();
        dao.createTable();
        dao.insertRecords(torbs); // perform inserts
        ResultSet rs = dao.retrieveRecords(); 
        System.out.println("ID\t\tINCOME\t\tPEP");
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String ID= rs.getString(2);
                double income=rs.getDouble(3);
                String pep=rs.getString(4);
                 System.out.println(ID + "\t" + income + "\t" + pep);
            }
        }
             catch (SQLException e ) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
 }
        String s = "";
        s=String.format("%10s\t %10s \t%10s \t%10s \t%10s \t%10s ", rs.getString(2), rs.getDouble(3), rs.getString(4));
        System.out.println(s);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println("Cur dt=" + timeStamp);
```

Dao.java file:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet; 

public class Dao {
    //Declare DB objects 
    DBConnect conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

        // constructor
        public Dao() { //create db object instance
         conn = new DBConnect();
    }
        public void createTable() {
             try {
             // Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database to create Table...");
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            // Execute create query
            System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");

            stmt = conn.connect().createStatement();

                String sql = "CREATE TABLE A_BILL__tab " +  "(pid INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +  " id VARCHAR(10), " + " income numeric(8,2), " + " pep VARCHAR(4), " + " PRIMARY KEY ( pid ))";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Created table in given database...");
            conn.connect().close(); //close db connection 
            } catch (SQLException se) {
            // Handle errors for JDBC
             se.printStackTrace();
             }
                  }
        public void insertRecords(BankRecords[] torbs) {
              try {
              // Execute a query


              System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
              stmt = conn.connect().createStatement();
          String sql = null;

                // Include all object data to the database table
              for (int i = 0; i < torbs.length; ++i) {

        // finish string assignment to insert all object data 
        // (id, income, pep) into your database table
                  String ID = torbs[i].getID();
                  double income=torbs[i].getIncome();
                  String pep=torbs[i].getPep();
        sql = "INSERT INTO A_BILL__tab(ID,INCOME, PEP) " + "VALUES (' "+ID+" ', ' "+income+" ', ' "+pep+" ' )";


        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                }
                   conn.connect().close();
               } catch (SQLException se) { se.printStackTrace(); }
         }
        public ResultSet retrieveRecords() {
             ResultSet rs = null;
              try {
             stmt = conn.connect().createStatement();
             System.out.println("Retrieving records from table...");
             String sql = "SELECT ID,income,pep from A_BILL__tab order by pep desc";

             rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
             conn.connect().close();
              } catch (SQLException se) { se.printStackTrace(); 
                }
             return rs;
              }
              }
```

Expected results would be printlns for the table functions (inserting records and so on), the headings, the data values for the first 10 files, and the date and time of when the program was run. Actual results were  some of the table functions, headings and then the time when the program ran not including when it errors me out with table already created. I'm not exactly sure where or how to fix these issues.

Comment: Does the code compile? Have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

you're getting this exception because every time you run your code, your main method calls `dao.createTable();`, and if the table is already created, it will throw an exception. So for this part, use a verification to check if the table is already created.

I'm not really sure where you created the variable `torbs`, but also make sure its properties are not null before inserting them to the database.